# Design for different Tokens

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

In my application I have Tokens. These Tokens are always enclosed in [ ]. 
A Token has an internal and an external Representation, e.g. a Variable´s internal Representation: [x] and the external Representation: [var=x].

I need to check Strings for Tokens a lot so I guessed it would be really helpful to have some kind of method that returns an Array of Tokens that are in this String.

To do this I thought about two approaches:

1. Have an Interface or abstract class Token and build subclasses for each Token.
   The benefits would be to be able to implement methods like getInternalRepresentation() and getExternalRepresentation() for each different Token. 
   The downside is: As different Tokens can appear in the same String and not every time every Token should be processed I´d need to call instanceof a lot to check whether the Token is one I want to process at that point or not.
2. I create an enum TokenType and a class Token which has this TokenType. Token contains the methods getInternalRepresentation() and getExternalRepresentation(), these return Strings based on the TokenType. 
    The benefit is that I don´t have to call instanceof as I can just check for the TokenType. 
    The downside is that I have two big methods that need to process every type of the enum and need to be adjusted, each time the enum gets adjusted. (Which could be the case as new Tokens could arise)

I also thought about combining the two approaches so that I have an abstract class Token with a final TokenType Field that gets set inside of the constructor. Then I could use polymorphism for getInternalRepresentation() and getExternalRepresentation() and ask for the type of the Token via the TokenType Field.
Which of the approaches is the best? Or am I missing out something?

Comment: What's the context here? Is your input string a structured syntax? If so, perhaps you need to be parsing the string against a grammar, then acting upon certain tokens if you wish to.

Comment: no, it is free text with Tokens. 
It´s user input, e.g. variable tokens inside of a textfield. Like 2*[a]+[b]

Comment: But what's the overall context? This feels a little like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you see, so I'm wondering if there's a broader solution that's applicable.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid calling `instanceof` on collection of elements with different types you can use visitor pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Interface, & can also use factory method for your Token.

public class TokenFactory{

```
public IToken getToken(String type) {

    IToken token = null;

    if (type.equals("internal")) {
        token = new InternalToken();
    }

    if (type.equals("external")) {
        token = new ExternalToken();
    }

    return token;
}
```

}

public interface IToken {

```
public void getTokenReprestation(); // your method & return type what u want
```

}

public class InternalToken implements IToken{

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.example.IToken#getTokenReprestation()
 */
@Override
public void getTokenReprestation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("this is Internal Token Type Object");
}
```

}

public class ExternalToken implements IToken{

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.example.IToken#getTokenReprestation()
 */
@Override
public void getTokenReprestation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("this is External Token Type Object");
}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    TokenFactory tokenFactory = new TokenFactory();

    IToken token = tokenFactory.getToken("internal");
    token.getTokenReprestation();

    IToken token = tokenFactory.getToken("external");
    token.getTokenReprestation();

}
```

// just a demo example for your understanding. hope it will help you. Thanks :)